# getElementById return null when apply it to select Option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, select

In my angular application I'm trying to execute some conditional code, when the result true I want to disable a selection option contain a list of dynamic object, when try to get the id of this select it return null !!

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.setScripts()
    this.http.get('api/cities').subscribe((cities: any[]) => {
      this.cities = cities;
    })

    this.http.get('api/user').subscribe(user => {
      this.currentUser = user
      localStorage.removeItem('currentUser')
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.currentUser))

      this.user.patchValue({
        firstName: this.currentUser.firstName,
        lastName: this.currentUser.lastName,
        email: this.currentUser.email,
        profession: this.currentUser.profession,
        gender: this.currentUser.gender,
        birthDate: this.currentUser.birthDate,
        phone: this.currentUser.phone,
        oldPassword: this.currentUser.oldPassword,
        password: this.currentUser.newPassword,
        address: this.currentUser.address,
        postalCode: this.currentUser.postalCode,
        city: this.currentUser.city._id
      })
    })
    this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    if (this.compareDatesByDays(new Date().toISOString(), JSON.parse(localStorage.currentUser).municipalityDateChange) < 10) {
      this.hideSelectMunicipality()
    }
  }



  hideSelectMunicipality(){
    $('#selectCity').prop('disabled', true);
   }
```

***html

```
  <div class="col-lg-7">
                  <select id="selectCity" name="city" class="custom-select form-control rounded" formControlName="city">
                    <option *ngFor="let city of cities" [value]="city._id" >{{city.name}}</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: Have your tried adding `[disabled]="condition"` to your `<select>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this,

```
hideSelectMunicipality(){
this.user.controls.city.disable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to use ngClass for this purpose and disable them on some condition

Answer (score 0):

I Think your currentUser municipalityDateChange days are below 10, So  "hideSelectMunicipality" function executed, Please to check user detail in database.